# How to use attribute appendTo in primeNG in component ContextMenu?

Tags: html, primeng

I´m trying to use the attribute `appendTo` in the component [ContextMenu](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/contextmenu), but I want attach the behavior to one element, like a div.

Comment: Solved
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/479

Answer (score 15):

on the element u want to append to add a hashtag #myHashTag
and on the prime element u want to append add:
[appendTo]="myHashTag" <- without the # sign

example:

```
<div class="recording-control-button" #stopbutton></div>

<p-confirmDialog [appendTo]="stopbutton"></p-confirmDialog>
```

Comment: I'm doing the same with a sidebar component, but no matter what element I attach it to, it still takes up the whole space/height on the left of the screen :-(

Comment: This solution worked with Angular 12 and PrimeNG 12 today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you're using Angular 2?

Based on the information on the api for primeng context menu here:

[PrimeNg context menu](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/contextmenu)

You need to use a Angular 2 template variable, see here:

[Angular 2 HTML variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars)

Comment: can you elaborate on the template variable im not quite sure on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it works - `[appendTo]="'body or template or any Id'"`

For example:
`<div #largeModal></div>` - define anywhere in html, but in your project

Define this menu primeng in your html
`<ng-template let-item="rowData" <p-menu #menu popup="popup" [model]="items"></p-menu> <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-list" label="Show" [appendTo]="'largeModal'" (click)="menu.toggle($event)"></button> </ng-template>`