# AppendTo problem with primeng menu\button

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a navbar with a button, when i click the button it opens the prime ng menu. Inside the primeng menu I inserted an [AppendTo]="body", actually I tried to bind it also to the external div but the problem is that when in the page I scroll down and subsequently open the menu through that button the menu it pops up in the middle of the page and not near the memo button, how can i fix this?

I expect the opened menu to stay close to the button both when the scrollbar hasn't been moved and when moved up and down.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the solution stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189195/how-to-use-attribute-appendto-in-primeng-in-component-contextmenu), because appending to `body` will not attach it to your button.